# Прервать переход по ссылке с использованием vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, navigationcontroller

Имеется подобный код ссылки:

```
 <a href="/login" v-on:click="link"><div class="button buttonB">Авторизация</div></a>
```

Необходимо прервать переход по ней и получить значение поля href и предположим вывести в командную строку. 
Я пытался выполнять return false при нажатие, но данный способ не останавливает.
Я знаю про существование **router-link**, но мне необходим функционал от тега a(пкм, открыть в новой вкладке)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <a href="/login" v-on:click="link">link</a>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    link(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log(e.currentTarget.href)
      // http://localhost:8080/login
    }
  }
}
</script>
```